# R - dataframe with text, replace string at position

Tags: r, substring

how can I replace date (or whatever text) with new string? Please do not use regexp since text could be always unique, but date is always on same position.

```
dt <-
  data.frame(
    id = c(1, 2, 3),
    text = c(
      "It was 2020-01-11",
      "It was 2020-03-21",
      "It was 2020-04-31"
    )
  )
```

result should be. I can extract that date via **substring** command. But how can I put it to my text column?

```
result <-
  data.frame(
    id = c(1, 2, 3),
    text = c(
      "It was 2020-01-01",
      "It was 2020-01-01",
      "It was 2020-01-01"
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result <- dt
result$text <- gsub(pattern = "^It was 2020\\-[0-9]{2}\\-[0-9]{2}$", replacement = "It was 2020-01-01", result$text)
```

or if you just wanna grab all text before the date patern group into the first group and replace the pattern that looks like a date (2020-mm-dd) with a fixed value.

```
result$text <- gsub(pattern = "^(.*) (2020\\-[0-9]{2}\\-[0-9]{2})(.*)", replacement = "\\1 2020-01-01 \\3", result$text)
```

Comment: hi gwd, my bad, sorry. i should write that solutions via regexp are not possible since text could be always unique. I just want to replace particular position in my string with another string.

Comment: pls define a particuular position you cannot define/reach via regex?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `substring` with `paste`

```
out <- transform(dt, text = paste0(substring(text, 1, 7), substring(text[1], 8)))
out 
#  id              text
#1  1 It was 2020-01-11
#2  2 It was 2020-01-11
#3  3 It was 2020-01-11
```

---

Or another option is `substr` assignment

```
dt$text <- as.character(dt$text)
substr(dt$text, 8, nchar(dt$text)) <- substring(dt$text[1], 8)
dt
#  id              text
#1  1 It was 2020-01-11
#2  2 It was 2020-01-11
#3  3 It was 2020-01-11
```